# Post method resends form instead of writing out message

Tags: python, webapp2

I've been pulling my hair on this one for 30 minutes, I don't know what I'm doing wrong since there are no syntax errors but the post method keeps resending the form when it should write out the message in the `else` statement

main.py

```
import webapp2
import dateValidation

form = """
<form>
<input type="text name="month">
<input type="text name="day">
<input type="text name="year">
<input type="submit">
</form>>

"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)

  def post(self):
        user_month=dateValidation.valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day=dateValidation.valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year=dateValidation.valid_year(self.request.get('year'))

        if not (user_month and user_day and user_year):
            self.response.out.write(form)
        else:
            self.response.out.write("Thanks, that's a totally valid day!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                               debug=True)
```

dateValidation.py:

```
months = ['January',
          'February',
          'March',
          'April',
          'May',
          'June',
          'July',
          'August',
          'September',
          'October',
          'November',
          'December']

def valid_month(month):
    if month:
        cap_Month=month.capitalize()
        if cap_month in months:
          return cap_month

def valid_day(day):
    if day and day.isdigit():
        day=int(day)
        if day>0 and day<32:
            return day

def valid_year(year):
    if year and year.isdigit():
        year=int(year)
        if year>1920 and year<2020:
            return year
```

Comment: have you debugged that the input going to the validation code is what you think it should be?

Comment: and are you sure that you aren't picking up extra whitespace is the strings you are passing into the validator?  Liberally add `strip()`

Comment: Try correcting the HTML.  Most of the `type` attributes are missing terminating quotes and there is an extra "greater than" sign at the end.